# Trying to get the name of the object whose collection array contains 'random'

Tags: java, arrays, json, object, jsonpath

I'm trying to get the names of the object whose collection array contains the word 'random'. Have tried various json path queries but couldn't get the right one.

```js
{
 "elements": [
        {
   "name": "My first element",
   "language": "French",
   "tags": ["Paris", "baguette", "Eiffel  tower"]
  },

  {
   "name": "randomOne",
   "language": "Gibberish",
   "tags": ["random", "plant, bag"]
  },

        {
   "name": "bliep",
   "language": "English",
   "tags": ["lamp", "table, bed, oven"]
  }

]}
```

Comment: What does this have to do with Java?

Comment: I'm planning to use the jsonpath library within my java project and need it to extract information from the json file

Comment: I don't see any Java code in your question. Or jsonpath for that matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried this question and able to get the names whose having 'random' in collection array.

```
$.elements[?(@.tags.indexOf('random') != -1)].name
```

Please update if it serves your purpose.

Answer (score 2):

**Try this :**

```js
const jsonObj = {
 "elements": [{
   "name": "My first element",
   "language": "French",
   "tags": ["Paris", "baguette", "Eiffel  tower"]
  },

  {
   "name": "randomOne",
   "language": "Gibberish",
   "tags": ["random", "plant, bag"]
  },

  {
   "name": "bliep",
   "language": "English",
   "tags": ["lamp", "table, bed, oven"]
  }

 ]
};

let obj = jsonObj.elements.find((obj) => obj.tags.includes('random'));

console.log(obj.name); // randomOne
```

Comment: The requirement is to find the names (plural). `Array.Find()` returns only the first match.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply:

1. Loop through `elements` with `Array.prototype.forEach()`
2. Find instances containing "random" with `Array.prototype.includes()`
3. Add found names to result array with `Array.prototype.push()`

See below:

```js
const jsondata = {
  elements: [{
      name: "My first element",
      language: "French",
      tags: ["Paris", "baguette", "Eiffel tower"]
    },
    {
      name: "randomOne",
      language: "Gibberish",
      tags: ["random", "plant, bag"]
    },
    {
      name: "bliep",
      language: "English",
      tags: ["lamp", "table, bed, oven"]
    }
  ]
};

const result = [];
jsondata.elements.forEach(elem => {
  if (elem.tags.includes("random")) {
    result.push(elem.name);
  }
});

console.log(result); // [ 'randomOne' ]
```